# How to get video streaming with react-native-video?

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, video-streaming

I have backend on nodejs  with the following code, where I use Range-based video streaming:

```js
router.get('/video/:id', authenticateToken, (req, res) => {
  const range = req.headers.range;
  if (!range) {
    res.status(400).send("Requires Range header");
  }

  // get video stats (about 61MB)
  const videoPath = `uploads/${req.params.id}`;
  const videoSize = fs.statSync(videoPath).size;

  // Parse Range
  // Example: "bytes=32324-"
  const CHUNK_SIZE = 10 ** 6; // 1MB
  const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ""));
  const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, videoSize - 1);

  // Create headers
  const contentLength = end - start + 1;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Content-Length": contentLength,
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
  };

  // HTTP Status 206 for Partial Content
  res.writeHead(206, headers);

  // create video read stream for this particular chunk
  const videoStream = fs.createReadStream(videoPath, { start, end });

  // Stream the video chunk to the client
  videoStream.pipe(res);
});
```

But react-native-video does not send any Range Headers and when I'm trying to get a mp4 video from the server I'm getting error:

```js
{"error": {"extra": -2147483648, "what": 1}}
```

using react-native-video package:

```js
<Video
  source={{
    uri: `http://*server ip*/video/${exercise.content}`,
    type: 'mp4',
  }}
/>
```

what should I use instead?

Comment: Do you use `express` or something similar on serverside?

Comment: @SilvanBregy yes I use express js as you can see in code and question tags

Comment: ah well didn't see.. :) Instead doing it on your own, try to statically serve your files with express.static. When your <video> tags url point to the video express does it for you. Do you want an example? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

express static solve my problem. thanks to @SilvanBregy

```
app.use('/video', express.static('uploads'))
```

Comment: What is express? i have the same issue but i don't understand the solution.

Comment: @bdroid Express is the NodeJS web framework I used. https://github.com/expressjs/express